# Android app demo recorder app?

Tags: android, video, recorder

This is not really a developer question but not sure where else to ask. I'm getting close to making a video tutorial for my android app. On windows I used something called "demobuilder" which is pretty cool, it records the screen as you demo your app (with voice over) and it produces a flash video.

I've been looking for something like that for android but haven't found anything that captures the screen to a video.

Can someone recommend an app that will help?

The alternative is pointing a webcam at my tablet which I think is a bit unprofessional.

Comment: There's no way for an app to capture the screen data at full frame rate on a stock Android phone as far as I know. An alternative (albeit a bit pricey perhaps) could be to connect the phone to some sort of video capture card with HDMI input. That's assuming that the phone(s) you'll be demoing your app on has HDMI/MHL output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem sometime ago. Like Michael said, it is hard to capture at full frame rate from the Android (or the emulator).

I ended up using [Screencast for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast). However, what I would probably do now was getting something like [Elgato](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00840353W). You connect the device trhough HDMI to that box and it allows you to record the HDMI output signal.

Comment: i've got a big app, it only runs on tablets. i'll demo it on a galaxy tab 8.9 which doesn't seem to have HDMI. screencast looks interesting, i'll try it out, thanks

Comment: it looks like i can get HDMI on my tablet for $40 
Galaxy Tab™ HDTV Adapter but the Elgato thing is a bit pricy.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to build your app for [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/), so that it'll run on your computer without emulation.  At that point, your usual screen cast tools all work.